# Log4Net: Logger only accepting INFO, missing all other levels

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, log4net, aop, log4net-configuration

In learning about AOP, im trying to apply everyone's best example: logging.
My setup is an asp.net mvc4 web project and a separate logging project with the logging defined.

I have managed to get the logging going, but for some reason i cant get it only logs INFO.

Here's my config file (Log4Net.config, Logging project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="DEBUG_APPENDER" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="..\Logs\application.log" />
    <additivity value="true" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="500KB" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_APPENDER"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

the class with the log code:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogAttribute:OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    private static ILog _logger;

    private static void CreateLogger(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
         _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogAttribute));
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        CreateLogger(args);
        _logger.Info("info test");
        _logger.Error("Error test, hopefully");
        _logger.Fatal("Fatal please ");
    }
}
```

The usage, on web project:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Log]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The view is just a Hello string on a page.

My log file,no matter i do only gives me

2016-04-05 19:12:39,241 [124] INFO  Logging.LogAttribute [(null)] - info test

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the content after every message then you need to add `immediateFlush` so content is written back to disk after each call. The reason this is false by default is because it increases the performance to not write with every call.

See [this documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.ImmediateFlush.html) for more info.

> #### Property Value
>
> The default behavior is to flush at the end of each append operation.
>   If this option is set to false, then the underlying stream can defer persisting the logging event to a later time.
>
> #### Remarks
>
> Avoiding the flush operation at the end of each append results in a performance gain of 10 to 20 percent. However, there is safety trade-off involved in skipping flushing. Indeed, when flushing is skipped, then it is likely that the last few log events will not be recorded on disk when the application exits. This is a high price to pay even for a 20% performance gain.

```
<appender name="DEBUG_APPENDER" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<immediateFlush value="true" />
<file value="..\Logs\application.log" />
<additivity value="true" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
<maxSizeRollBackups value="1" />
<maximumFileSize value="500KB" />
<rollingStyle value="Size" />
<staticLogFileName value="true" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

Comment: @sergio - You might also try changing the locking mechanism: `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />`

Comment: @sergio - Also if you are just changing the xml make sure that you either have an assembly attribute to re-init log4net to load in the changes OR recycle your app pool. This is because the xml is read in only once for the appdomain when the app first loads.

Comment: this is so crazy, i will create a project from scratch and see whats going on and report back.

Comment: @sergio - by the way if you want an assembly level attribute that you can use to ensure the `log4netconfig.xml` (or whatever you named it) file is monitored you can add this: `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @"Log4NetConfig.xml", Watch = true)]`. This will ensure that changes to the config file are recognized as soon as the file is saved to disk.